# Call the UI of R built-in functions

Tags: r, shiny

I want to be able to design a set of UI that can call R's built-in functions, but the current problem lies in the data selection when calling the function. I need to return the calculation result of a function to my UI interface so that another function can be arbitrary Select the variables in the current environment as the input of the function. This is my current code. Can anyone give me some suggestions or some cases?

```
library(shiny)
function_choose = c("sin","cos") 



ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('f', 'function_choose', function_choose,
                selected = function_choose[[1]]),
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.f=='sin'",
                     mainPanel(
                       selectInput('sin_dat','data',c("I want to show all the variables in the workspace here ")),
                       actionButton(inputId = "sin_run",label = "RUN")
                     )
    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.f=='cos'",
                     mainPanel(
                       selectInput('workspace','data',c("I want to show all the variables in the workspace here "))),
                       actionButton(inputId = "cos_run",label = "RUN")
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text")
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3)
  
  observeEvent(input$sin_run,{
    data_sined <- sin(data)
    output$text <- renderText({
      "data_sined is created"
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$cos_run,{
    data_cosed<- cos(data)
    output$text <- renderText({
      "data_cosed is created"
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What do you mean by “call the UI of R built-in functions” and “UI that can call R's built-in functions”?

Comment: Sorry, I may not describe it very clearly. I mean to call R's built-in functions through UI options

Answer (score 0):

I changed the logic of your app to make it less complicated, I hope this is still ok for your purpose. We can use `ls()` to get a character vector of all variables in the global (or any other) environment. If we define a vector `function_choose` in the global environment, then this will be available too. We could easily circumvent this by defining the `choices` argument inside `selectInput` or by specifying a names `pattern` that is selected by `ls()`. Once we have selected a variable, the `input$data` returns a character vector. To access the underyling data based on a character vector we use `get()`.

```
library(shiny)

function_choose = c("sin","cos") 

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    
    
    selectInput('f', 'function_choose', choices = function_choose,
              selected = function_choose[1]),

    selectInput('data','data', choices = ls()), 
    
    actionButton(inputId = "run",label = "RUN")
    
    ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text")
  )
  
),

server = function(input, output,session) {
  
  res <- eventReactive(input$run, {
    
    dat <- get(input$data)
    
    switch(input$f,
           sin = sin(dat),
           cos = cos(dat)
           )
    })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    res()
  })

  
})
```

Comment: It's also worth commenting that it is rarely (never?) a good idea to nest `reactive`s as OP did in their sample code.